# Jasypt - Poor performance on Solaris

Tags: performance, encryption, java-8, solaris, jasypt

I'm using a PooledPBEStringEncryptor to decrypt some strings. I'm running my test on multiple threads.

I'm executing the method below on multiple threads

```
public static long decryptJasypt (String str)
{
  long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
  encryptor.decrypt(str);
  return System.currentTimeMillis()-time;
}
```

where

```
encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();

encryptor.setPoolSize(4);
```

I'am running the same test on Ubuntu and on Solaris. The same test takes 10 longer on Solaris to complete.

For Solaris, as security providers I used either

```
sun.security.pkcs11.SunPKCS11 ${java.home}/lib/security/sunpkcs11-solaris.cfg
```

or

```
com.oracle.security.ucrypto.UcryptoProvider ${java.home}/lib/security/ucrypto-solaris.cfg
```

For the first provider my threads are staying here:

```
"Thread-86" #104 prio=5 os_prio=64 tid=0x00000000014ab800 nid=0x78 runnable [0xffff80ffb3971000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_CloseSession(Native Method)
at sun.security.pkcs11.SessionRef.dispose(Session.java:171)
at sun.security.pkcs11.Session.close(Session.java:120)
at sun.security.pkcs11.SessionManager.closeSession(SessionManager.java:232)
at sun.security.pkcs11.SessionManager.killSession(SessionManager.java:174)
at sun.security.pkcs11.Token.killSession(Token.java:311)
at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Digest.engineReset(P11Digest.java:144)
at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Digest.engineDigest(P11Digest.java:194)
at sun.security.pkcs11.P11Digest.engineDigest(P11Digest.java:157)
at java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate.engineDigest(MessageDigest.java:592)
at java.security.MessageDigest.digest(MessageDigest.java:365)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES1Core.deriveCipherKey(PBES1Core.java:279)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES1Core.init(PBES1Core.java:250)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineInit(PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.java:221)
```

While for the other one here:

```
Thread-73" #91 prio=5 os_prio=64 tid=0x0000000001733800 nid=0x6b runnable [0xffff80ffb467e000]
java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
at com.oracle.security.ucrypto.NativeDigest.nativeInit(Native Method)
at com.oracle.security.ucrypto.NativeDigest.engineUpdate(NativeDigest.java:167)
- locked <0x00000003402108d0> (a com.oracle.security.ucrypto.NativeDigest$MD5)
at java.security.MessageDigest$Delegate.engineUpdate(MessageDigest.java:584)
at java.security.MessageDigest.update(MessageDigest.java:335)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES1Core.deriveCipherKey(PBES1Core.java:278)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBES1Core.init(PBES1Core.java:250)
at com.sun.crypto.provider.PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.engineInit(PBEWithMD5AndDESCipher.java:221)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1393)
at javax.crypto.Cipher.init(Cipher.java:1326)
```

Could you please advice on how I should troubleshoot this. Are there any known issues for jasypt running on Solaris ?

My test consists in creating an array with some simple strings encrypted with jasypt (it has 30 items in it) and then starting 100 threads. Each thread decrypts the items in the array 10 times.

Results on Solaris: a thread takes from 39 to 79 seconds to complete this task

Results on Linux: a thread takes from 2 to 7 seconds to complete this task

On linux machine: 1 physical processor, 8 cores

On solaris i have a virtual machine that resides on machine with 2 physical processors each with 4 cores and 8 virtual processors.

Note: we experienced slowness when decrypting data even on a solaris sparc with 256 cores. I wasn't able though to perform my tests in that env.

```
public static ArrayList<String> ar = new ArrayList();
public static PooledPBEStringEncryptor encryptor;
static
{
    Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
    encryptor = new PooledPBEStringEncryptor();
    encryptor.setPoolSize(4);
    encryptor.setPassword("xxxxxx");

    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        ar.add(encryptJasyptValue("false"));
    }
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        ar.add(encryptJasyptValue(""+i));
    }
    for (int i=0;i<10;i++){
        ar.add(encryptJasyptValue("true"));
    }


}


public static long encryptJasypt (String str){
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
return System.currentTimeMillis()-time;
}

public static long decryptJasypt (String str){
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    encryptor.decrypt(str);
    return System.currentTimeMillis()-time;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{


    int noTreads =100;
    if(args.length>0 && args[0]!=null) {
         noTreads = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<noTreads;i++)
    {
       new MyThread().start();
    }


 }
}

class MyThread extends Thread {
public void run() {

    long time=0;
    for (int k=0;k<10;k++) {
        for (int i = 0; i < CryptoUtil.ar.size(); i++) {
            time += CryptoUtil.decryptJasypt(CryptoUtil.ar.get(i));
        }
    }
    System.out.println("took d="+time);
}

}
```

Comment: You need to be more specific with what specifically you test, and what you mean by "takes 10 longer". A lot of factors are in play when you do java performance comparison. Do you just run one or many tests, do you encrypt small or large pices of data, do your time include loading of encryption providers or not etc.. Have you done warm-up test to trigger the JIT compilation etc.

Comment: You also don't specify the **hardware** being used in either case.  Without the hardware being specified, performance comparisons are completely meaningless.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad.  Question does not have enough detail to provide an answer, and the poster doesn't seem inclined to provide it.